# How to fix error when Importing Torchvision that return PILLOW_VERSION error

Tags: ubuntu, python, docker

I have a problem with building docker with a base of pytorch+cuda. This is the dockerfile that I used

```
#FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-base-ubuntu16.04
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.2-base-ubuntu18.04
# Install some basic utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
    python3-pip\
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /app
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user

# Install Miniconda
RUN curl -so ~/miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.7.12.1-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh \
 && ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda \
 && rm ~/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/home/user/miniconda/bin:$PATH
#ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false

# Create a Python 3.6 environment
RUN /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py36 python=3.6.5 \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda clean -ya
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=py36
ENV CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user/miniconda/envs/$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
ENV PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH

# CUDA 9.0-specific steps
RUN conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install HDF5 Python bindings
RUN conda install -y h5py=2.8.0 \
 && conda clean -ya
RUN pip3 install h5py-cache==1.0

# Install Torchnet, a high-level framework for PyTorch
RUN pip3 install torchnet==0.0.4

# Install Requests, a Python library for making HTTP requests
RUN conda install -y requests=2.19.1 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install Graphviz
RUN conda install -c anaconda graphviz \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install OpenCV3 Python bindings
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libcanberra-gtk-module \
 && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN conda install -y -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install Numpy
RUN conda install -y -c anaconda numpy \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install matplotlib
RUN conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install pandas
RUN conda install -c anaconda pandas \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install Nano
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nano

#Copy data
RUN mkdir sfsnet
COPY /SfSNet/ /app/sfsnet/

# Set the default command to python3
#CMD ["python3"]
```

The problem is whenever I try to import torchvision it always return error related to PIL.

```
 PIL.__version__ 
'7.0.0'
>>> import torchvision
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/miniconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torchvision import datasets
  File "/home/user/miniconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .fakedata import FakeData
  File "/home/user/miniconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/fakedata.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import transforms
  File "/home/user/miniconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .transforms import *
  File "/home/user/miniconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import functional as F
  File "/home/user/miniconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, PILLOW_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name 'PILLOW_VERSION'
```

I have read other post that this is because of bug on older version and should have been fixed in newer version of Torchvision yet the problem still persist [(reference)](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/612). Can someone give me some solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu `pip` installs packages for the Python v2 environment, and you are using Python v3. Use `pip3` instead.

**Edit**: I don't see `pillow` installed by your Dockerfile. In addition, it appears that everything can be installed with Conda, and perhaps **should be** installed that way, otherwise it could be not included in the Conda environment.

Comment: Hi, can you show which part I should change? I have already edit the dockerfile to use pip3 instead of pip but the problem still persist. I even install PIL again inside the docker with pip3 but still doesn't resolve it

Comment: Can't run your Dockerfile right now (but look way to complicated...). Start the container and run python in it, then do `import site;print(site.getusersitepackages());print(site.getsitepackages())`. This will print a bunch of directories, you can search your packages in the container and see if they are all there, if they are outside these directories this will give you a hint. You can also check that `sys.path` points to these directories.

Answer (score 0):

Pillow version 7.0 includes breaking changes to the API which are not fully incorporated into the torchvision version you are using. The fix for this has been published for Linux & Mac to pipy/Conda. pip install torchvision==0.5.0 is the requirement which should fix the breaking API issue.

Opened an issue with some of the related issues.

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1774